# undefined local variable or method `user' rails controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Beginner here...I'm trying to display an image but i'm getting the "undefined local variable or method `user'" error message.  I think I know whats happening - there is no method but i just can't seem to get it working correctly with what i've tried.  I've got a 'projects' model & controller...and a 'versions' model & controller.  (pretty sure its just a controller issue so i've posted those files...just let me know if i need to post other files).  I believe whats happening is when a user creates a new version the user_id is not being set (at least when I run "version.user_id" for a certain version id, it returns nil).  How would i go about...

1) making sure the user_id is set in the db when the logged in user creates a version?
2) make sure there is a method in the versions index so i can display the profile pic for that user_id to created the version??

thanks in advance for any help...

THE ERROR:

```
NameError in Versions#index
Showing /Users/user/Documents/clones/collab/app/views/versions/_version.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x00000101b39f28>:0x0000010828c1d0>
```

THE VERSIONS CONTROLLER:

```
class VersionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_project

  def new
    @version = Version.new
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @version = Version.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    # @user = User.where(:id => @version.user_id) first figure out how to set user_id on new versions (its nil now)
    @versions = Version.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @version = @project.verions.build(version_params)
    if @version.save
      flash[:success] = "You've successfully added a version of this project"
      redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy

  end

  private

    def find_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def version_params
      params.require(:version).permit(:title, :project_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

VERSIONS NEW VIEW:

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Version') %>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-5 no-pad">
    <h1>Add a new version to this project</h1>
    <%= bootstrap_form_for @version, :url => project_versions_path do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.text_field :title %>

      <div class="well">
        <h4>Drag and Drop your file here:</h4>
        <%= image_tag("wavicon-large-grey.png", alt: "add file") %>
      </div>

      <%= f.button "Create Now! ", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

VERSIONS INDEX VIEW:

```
<% provide(:title, @versions ) %>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <section class="no-pad col-md-9">

    <%= render :partial => '/projects/project_header' %>

    <h4>Version History</h4>

    <%= will_paginate %>

    <ul class="versions">
      <% @project.versions.first(5).each do |version| %> 

        <%= render version %>

      <% end %>
    </ul>

    <!-- CAN REFACTOR TO BELOW FOR CLEANER CODE
    <ul class="versions">
      <%= render @versions %>
    </ul>
    -->

    <%= will_paginate %>

  </section>
</div>
```

_VERSION.HTML.ERB PARTIAL (linked to in index file above)

```
<li>
  <%= link_to project_version_path(@project, version) do %>
    <h6><%= image_tag user.image_url(:collaborator_thumb).to_s, :class => "profile-pic-thumb" %><%= version.title %>...</h6>
    <span class="timestamp pull-right">
      Created <%= time_ago_in_words(version.created_at) %> ago
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    </span>

  <% end %>
</li>
```

VERSION.RB MODEL (not sure if needed):

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve following error

`undefined local variable or method 'user' for #<#<Class:0x00000101b39f28>:0x0000010828c1d0>`

In your `_version.html.erb` partial,

Replace

```
<h6><%= image_tag user.image_url(:collaborator_thumb).to_s, :class => "profile-pic-thumb" %><%= version.title %>...</h6>
```

With

```
<h6><%= image_tag version.user.image_url(:collaborator_thumb).to_s, :class => "profile-pic-thumb" %><%= version.title %>...</h6>
```

Note `version.user.image_url` instead of `user.image_url`. You are getting error because `user` variable is not defined. BUT `version` is defined so to access the associated `user` record you can simply use `version.user`.

**UPDATE**

The association with `User` model is missing in `Version` model. Set it as below:

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ## ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions
  ## ...
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

To store the `user_id` for a `Version` instance. Update the `new` action in your controller as below:

```
def new 
  @version = @project.versions.build(user_id: @project.user_id) 
end
```

In the versions `new` view, add a hidden field for `user_id`:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
```

Update the versions `index` view as below:

```
   <ul class="versions">
      <% @project.versions.first(5).each do |version| %>    
        <%= render partial: "version", object: version %>    
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Kirti, when I do that I get a similar error...NameError in Versions#index
Showing /Users/user/Documents/clones/collab/app/views/versions/_version.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `user' for #<#<Class:0x00000101b39f28>:0x000001057e3690>

Comment: @BB500: You also need to put has_many and belongs_to association in Version and User model.

Comment: I just noticed, you say that you have `version.user_id` field but you have not set the association in model.

Comment: thanks Kirti - now i'm getting the following error...NoMethodError in Versions#index Showing /Users/user/Documents/clones/collab/app/views/versions/_version.html.erb where line #3 raised: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass.  (i've updated my models)

Comment: Hey Kirti - Sorry that chat page keeps timing out on me.  But it Worked!!!  thanks so much for your help.  I will go ahead and award yours as the correct answer...and edit the page to reflect your steps.

Comment: Hey Kirti - i just posted another question related to what you helped me with (it wasn't quite right)...just in case you wanted to take a look.  thx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376896/wrong-user-id-being-stored-when-creating-a-new-record

Comment: Hi @KirtiThorat, can you help with this? I think it is my new method/action causing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58044609/nameerror-undefined-local-variable-or-method-clock-entry-params-for-clocken?noredirect=1#comment102492320_58044609

Answer (score 1):

you need to do in _VERSION.HTML.ERB:

```
<h6><%= image_tag @version.user.image_url(:collaborator_thumb).to_s, :class => "profile-pic-thumb" %><%= version.title %>...</h6>
```

as you haven't defined user anywhere, by doing this you will be able to access `user` associated with `@version`.

You also need to put `has_many` and `belongs_to` association in `Version` and `User` model.

Comment: thanks saurabh - (totally forgot to add that in the models).  but now even i get the following error...NoMethodError in Versions#index
Showing /Users/user/Documents/clones/collab/app/views/versions/_version.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Comment: it seems like calling version.user is giving a nil value for the user_id.  (the versions user is always nil)